# Duplicate Phone number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicate-data

Because of poor data entry policies, there are a lot of duplicate phone numbers to the same customers.
I need to write a query that will list all customers with the same phone number.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your query look like so far?  Stack Overflow isn't a "write me a query" site, you need to show some effort.

Comment: Depending on your data format you may want to strip non-numeric characters (if any) before comparing numbers.

Comment: And what is your table design? Do you have a PK on the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH dupes AS
(
  SELECT Phone_Number
  FROM dbo.Customer_Table
  GROUP BY Phone_Number
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT c.Customer_Name, dupes.Phone_Number
  FROM dupes 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Customer_Table AS c
  ON dupes.Phone_Number = c.Phone_Number;
```